# How to show that a sum is inclosed by two values / bounds?

Tags: calculus, integration, summation, improper-integrals, riemann-sum

**Show that this holds for all c>0**

**$\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{c}} \le \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 + c} \le \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{c}} + \frac{1}{c}$**

> I'd really appreciate it if some can tell me if my proof is valid (I checked the answer and they did it in a much complicated
> way so I felt this might be incorrect even if it feels like it proves something). Anyways here is my take on it:

> The first thing I wanna do is use Cauchy's integral test to see if the sum converges. I still don't fully understand why I picked 0 as a lower bound for the integral (I did it because of the sum starts $a_0$, but I'd appreciate if someone explained it for me assuming I'm even correct).

$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\frac{x}{\sqrt{c}})^2+1}dx = \lim_{R \to \infty}[\frac{arctan(\frac{x}{\sqrt{c}})}{\sqrt{c}}]_{0}^{R} = \lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{arctan(\frac{R}{\sqrt{c}})}{\sqrt{c}} - \frac{arctan(\frac{0}{\sqrt{c}})}{\sqrt{c}} = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{c}}$.

> Now I know the integral converges and to $\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{c}}$

According to Cauchy's integral test, the sum and the integral will converge the same way as n goes to infinity, so I assumed I can now compare the bounds in the question with this.

$\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{c}} \le \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2 + c}  = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{c}} \le \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{c}} + \frac{1}{c}$

> **So finally, is this an okay proof? Did I assume too much without proving? Is this even correct?**

Comment: You seem to be missing the summand after the $\Sigma$.

Comment: Oh shit I forgot, but it's all fixed now. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: You did not relate the series to the integral, even less did you prove any inequality. Why is the integral lower than the series? Where does the $\frac1c$ term come from and how is the upper bound justified? Can you recall precisedly the Cauchy integral test to which you refer? How does it give you inequalities?

Comment: The summand is still missing at the end of your post.

Comment: I mean according to my understading of Cauchy's test, I can rewrite the sum as a function and then show that it converges or diverges, then the same thing will happen to the sum. It has to do with Riemann's sum I guess but in the long run as n goes to infinity it doesn't really matter which type of Riemann's sum it is since we are interested when goes to infinity This way I related it the integral to the sum. I agree with you, it still doesn't feel good enough but I don't know how to do it better.

Comment: And the 1/c is already in the question. If you add 1/c to the value I got when the sum converges then obviously it will be bigger. That way I proved the upper bound will be greater for n>c. The lower bound and the value I got when the sum converges are equal so the lower bound holds too.

Comment: No, you neither proved the lower bound nor the upper bound. And the $1/c$ was in the question but you justify it nowhere. And when applying Cauchy (which anyway only tells you the series converge, nothing more unless you are more precise), why do you integrate $\frac{1}{(\frac{x}{\sqrt{c}})^2+1}$ and not $\frac1{x^2+c}?$

Comment: I noticed I've skipped the part where I factorized out a 1/c here. I facotrized 1/c from 1/(x^2+c) then I took the square root of c and raised to  2 with x to make it easy to integrate using arctan.

Answer (score 2):

Define for $c > 0$ the function $f_c(x) = (x^2+c)^{-1}$ and let $$S(c) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_c(n). \tag{1}$$  Then since $f_c$ is a strictly decreasing function on $x \in [0,\infty)$, it follows that $$S(c) = \int_{x=0}^\infty f_c(\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor ) \, dx \ge \int_{x=0}^\infty f_c(x) \, dx. \tag{2}$$  We can call $(2)$ the inequality arising from *left endpoint discretization of $f_c$*.  Similarly, $$S(c) - \frac{1}{c} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_c(n) = \int_{x=0}^\infty f_c(\left\lceil x \right\rceil) \, dx \le \int_{x=0}^\infty f_c(x) \, dx, \tag{3}$$ which is the corresponding *right endpoint discretization*.  The two inequalities combined yield the compound
$$I(c) \le S(c) \le I(c) + \frac{1}{c}, \tag{4}$$ where $$\begin{align}
I(c) &= \int_{x=0}^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2 + c} \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{c}} \lim_{r \to \infty} \left[\arctan \frac{x}{\sqrt{c}}\right]_{x=0}^r \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{c}}. \tag{5}
\end{align}$$
This concludes the proof.

---

The main conceptual difference between my proof and yours is that I explicitly use a property of $f_c$ (namely, that it is a strictly decreasing function) to establish upper and lower bounds on the sum $S_c$; you have not done this.  By referring to a convergence test (Cauchy), you are not actually making a claim that indicates whether the integral is greater than or less than the sum, and that is the flaw in your proof.  They may have the same convergence properties, but this can also be true for a function that is *non-monotone*, which would pose problems for bounding it above and below by a suitable integral expression.

Comment: +1 :  I like the analysis at the end of your answer, which diagnoses the original poster's work.

Comment: hanks for the help but there are somethings I don't understand here. For example what is the difference between these two in (2) ∫⌈fc(x)⌉dx≤∫fc(x)dx

I mean, aren't they kind of the same, why the less than or equal to sign? What does the sign that looks like an "absolute value sign" doing?

Comment: $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the floor function, which gives the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.  Similarly, $\lceil x \rceil$ is the ceiling function, which gives the least integer greater than or equal to $x$.  So for example $$\lfloor 3.5 \rfloor = 3, \quad \lfloor -1.999 \rfloor = -2, \quad \lfloor 100 \rfloor = 100, \\ \lceil 3.5 \rceil = 4, \quad \lceil -1.999 \rceil = -1, \quad \lceil 100 \rceil = 100.$$  Hence for a strictly decreasing function satisfying $f(a) \le f(b)$ whenever $a \ge b$, it follows that $f(\lfloor x \rfloor) \ge f(x)$.

Comment: @user2661923 Please note that I made a typographical error in my answer:  I had written $\lfloor f_c(x) \rfloor$ which is incorrect, instead of the correct expression $f_c(\lfloor x \rfloor)$.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the series $~\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}~$ is known to be convergent and equal $~\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}.$

Also, you have that the terms in the series $~\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + c}$ are each positive.  So, that infinite series is strictly increasing, and bounded above by $~\dfrac{\pi^2}{6},~$ and so must be convergent.

Therefore, the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + c} = \frac{1}{c} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + c}$ must also be a convergent series.

---

$\displaystyle \frac{d ~\arctan \left(\frac{x}{k}\right)}{dx} = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{x^2}{k^2}} \times \frac{1}{k} = \frac{k}{k^2 + x^2}.$

Therefore,

$$\int \frac{k ~dx}{x^2 + k^2} = \arctan \left(\frac{x}{k}\right) \implies $$

$$\int \frac{dx}{x^2 + k^2} = \frac{1}{k} \times \arctan \left(\frac{x}{k}\right).$$

Let

$$I = \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2 + c} = \lim_{b \to \infty} \left[ ~\int_0^b \frac{dx}{x^2 + c}  ~\right] \tag1 $$

$$= \frac{1}{\sqrt{c}} \times \lim_{b \to \infty} \left[ ~\arctan \left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{c}}\right) - \arctan \left(\frac{0}{\sqrt{c}}\right) ~\right]$$

$$= \frac{1}{\sqrt{c}} \times \frac{\pi}{2}.$$

---

The problem can be completed by :

- Constructing a set of tall rectangles (set $T$) and short rectangles (set $S$).
- Showing that the combined area of the rectangles in set $~T~$ is 
  $~\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + c}.$
- Showing that the combined area of the rectangles in set $~S~$ is 
  $~\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + c}.$
- Showing that the region represented by the tall rectangles completely covers the area under the curve, represented by the integral $I$, defined in (1) above.
- Showing that the region represented by the short rectangles is completely covered by the area under the curve, represented by the integral $I$, defined in (1) above.

Assuming that each of the above bullet points is accomplished, this will imply that

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + c} > \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{c}} > \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + c} \implies $$

$$\frac{1}{c} + \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{c}} > \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2 + c}.$$

---

Note that the integrand represented in (1) above, $~\dfrac{1}{x^2 + c}~$ is always positive, and is strictly decreasing, as $x$ goes from $~0 \to \infty.$

Note further, that for each $~k \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}$, the *height* of the integrand at $~x=k~$ is $~\dfrac{1}{k^2 + c}.$

Consider the region under the curve, of the integrand in (1) above, as $~x~$ goes from $~k~$ to $~k + 1$.  This region is completely covered by the tall rectangle whose vertices are

$$\left(k,0\right), ~(k+1,0), ~\left(k, ~\left[\frac{1}{k^2 + c} \right] ~\right), ~\left(k+1, ~\left[\frac{1}{k^2 + c} \right] ~\right),$$

and this tall rectangle has an area of $~\displaystyle \frac{1}{k^2 + c}.$

Similarly, as $~x~$ goes from $~k~$ to $~k+1,~$ the area under the curve completely covers the short rectangle whose vertices are

$$\left(k,0\right), ~(k+1,0), ~\left(k, ~\left[\frac{1}{[k+1]^2 + c} \right] ~\right), ~\left(k+1, ~\left[\frac{1}{[k+1]^2 + c} \right] ~\right),$$

and this short rectangle has an area of $\displaystyle \frac{1}{[k+1]^2 + c}.$

So, when you consider the combined area of all of the tall rectangles vs the area under the curve vs the combined area of the short rectangles, the bullet point tasks of the previous section are accomplished.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!